# Symfony 4 / FosREST : API routes return 404 but not web routes

Tags: symfony4, fosrestbundle

I'm setting up a classic symfony 4.3 project (aka a web site) in multi-languages and all routes are OK. I would like to expose some data with an simple API REST (only 3,4 routes with method GET) so i have installed FOSRestBundle 2.5. I know this version is compatible with SF 4.*.

The problem is my API routes return all 404 BUT NOT the "web" routes. I fllow symfony doc and FOSREST doc and some tutorials.
In fos_rest.yaml, i have declared the two types of routes in `rules` argument. I have separeted the controllers for web and controller for API in two directories (the two directories are mount in services.yaml)

Here the FOS REST configuration :
config/packages/fos_rest.yaml

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false
    body_listener: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: [ json ], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/', priorities: [ 'html', '*/*'], fallback_format: ~, prefer_extension: true }
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
```

config/services.yaml:

```
services:
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    App\ControllerApi\:
        resource: '../src/ControllerApi'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

And annotations definitions :
config/routes/annotations.yaml

```
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#localized-routing-i18n
web_controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        en: /
        fr: /{_locale}
        de: /{_locale}
        es: /{_locale}
        pt: /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app_locales%'
    defaults:
        _locale: '%locale%'

# Controller for Rest API
rest_controller:
    resource: ../../src/ControllerApi/
    type: annotation
    prefix: /api
```

Web controllers are basics and extends `AbstractController`. For API controller, here an exemple :

```php
namespace App\ControllerApi;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\AbstractFOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

final class fooApiController extends AbstractFOSRestController 
{
    /**
     * @param string $id
     *
     * @return View
     *
     * @Rest\Get("/demo/{$id}", name="api_demo")
     */
    public function getSimpleDataById($id)
    {
        /** @var Dso $dso */
        $data = $this->myCustomManager->getData($id);
        if (!$data instanceof CustomEntity) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        return View::create($data, Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Here's an exemple of route generated (example with homepage) :

```sh
www-data@php:~/symfony$ php bin/console debug:router | grep home
  homepage.en                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /                                      
  homepage.fr                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/                            
  homepage.de                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/                            
  homepage.es                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/                            
  homepage.pt                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/
```

All is ok (and others routes for web too).

Here's with API:

```sh
www-data@php:~/symfony$ php bin/console debug:router | grep api 
api_demo               GET      ANY      ANY    /api/demo/{$id}
```

So i curl the two :

```sh
curl --head http://symfony.local
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.14
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=336b94195892ebb5a3b4e7f2d2799fbb; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=lax
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private, s-maxage=3600
Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2019 13:26:05 GMT
X-Debug-Token: 5653c7
# Works with others URL...

curl --head http://symfony.local/api/demo/m42
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.14
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private
Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2019 13:27:03 GMT
```

I don't find the error.
Thanks for reading and answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a starting solution. I have changed my conf on fos_rest.yaml :

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false
    body_listener: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: [ json ], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
        formats:
            json: true
    zone:
        - { path: ^/api/* }
```

I have removed the rule '^/' and adding the zone. And the 404 wasn't here.

There was an error too on annotation in controller:
Here's the correct syntax :

```php
/**
     * @Rest\View()
     * @Rest\Get("/demo/{id}", name="api_demo")
     *
     * @param string $id
     *
     * @return View
     */
    public function getSimpleDataById(string $id): View
```

Comment: And there was an error in annotation on controller :