# Symfony 5 tests of API endpoints return html with redirect

Tags: php, api, symfony, testing, fosrestbundle

In a migration from Symfony 3.4 to Symfony 5.2 I'm facing following issue only in tests (in the application it works):

- FOSRest
- Symfony 5
- Lexik

fos_rest.yaml

```
fos_rest:
    body_listener:
        enabled: true
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/v1', priorities: [ 'json' ], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
    zone:
        - { path: ^/v1/* }
```

security.yaml

```yaml
api_login:
  pattern: ^/v1/login
  stateless: true
  anonymous: true
  provider: mg_users
  json_login:
    provider: mg_users
    check_path: /v1/login
    require_previous_session: false
    username_path: email
    password_path: password
    success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
    failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

Functional tests againt API endpoints that require authentication return following output if I try to output the response:

REQUEST

```php
/** @var KernelBrowser $client */
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request(
  'POST',
  '/v1/login',
  [],
  [],
  [
    'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
  ],
  '{"email":"admin@email.it","password":"admin"}'
);
```

RESPONSE

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='https://local.api.it/v1/login'" />

        <title>Redirecting to https://local.api.it/v1/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="https://local.api.it/v1/login">https://local.api.it/v1/login</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

This issue appears only with those pages/endpoints that require auhentication.
If I use `$client->followRedirect()` the request does no longer contain email and password and I receive an INVALID JSON error in HTML instead of being JSON.

So questions:

- How can I prevent to to be redirected?
- Why does it happen only in the test environment?
- How can I receive a JSON error insteead of a HTML?

Comment: Are you sure your client is requesting the url ```https://local.api.it/v1/login``` exactly? My first guess would be that the client is requesting http and being redirected to https.

Comment: It is possible that the FormatListener is overwriting the format request. Have you tried to pass an Accept header (`HTTP_ACCEPT` in $server parameter) with `application/json`? Have you enabled the profiler in test env? The JsonLoginAuthenticator returns `true` to `support` call?

Answer (score 0):

In `json_login` is username_path and password_path are necessary ? you can specify like this and remove both items:

```yaml
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        api_entity_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\YourUserEntity
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
        api_login:
            pattern: ^/v1/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: api_entity_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /v1/login
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false
```

Did you add your route in access_control:

```yaml
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/v1/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/v1, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY}
```

When i'm looking at https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html and  `vendor/symfony/http-client-contracts/HttpClientInterface.php` i've seen there is only 3 arguments, the third one is for options and you have 4 more arguments. Are you using something else ?
And why "CONTENT_TYPE" instead "content-type" ?

It looks like a question i've posted a year and a half: [Symfony 4 / FosREST : API routes return 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113520/symfony-4-fosrest-api-routes-return-404-but-not-web-routes).

Comment: It's a KernelBrowser client. It's a functional test. The problem is reproducible only in the functional tests, not in the final application (that works)

Comment: I don't know this component, i think i can't help you anymore, sorry.

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm blocked for this issue and I cannot migrate from Symfony 3.4 to Symfony 5.... It's really frustrating  :(

Answer (score 0):

My guess will be To check your routes.yaml file that it contains the right path for my example like this

```
Api_login_check:
  path: /v1/login_check
  methods:  [POST]
```

and your security.yaml under firewalls

```
login:
            pattern: ^/v1/login_check
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /v1/login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

and default your FOS_REST format listener to

```
format_listener:
      rules:
        - { path: '^/v1', priorities: [ 'json', 'html', '*/*' ], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
        - { path: '^/', priorities: [ 'html', '*/*' ], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
```